# Firefox Not Obeying childList Config Param in Mutation Observer

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers

Here's how I'm declaring my mutation observer:

```
observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        switch (mutation.type) {
            case 'childList':
                // Do Stuff
            break;
        }
    })

observer.observe(
    document.getElementById('contentEditableElement'), 
    {
        attributes: false, 
        childList: true, 
        characterData: false
    }
);
```

The above code works totally fine in Chrome. When I drag and drop HTML elements into the content editable area, the observer fires when the element is dropped *both* directly on the observed element and when an element is dropped into a child element of the observed element.

In FireFox (v 29.0.1), the observer only fires when elements are added directly to the observed elements and not its children. Why?

Comment: What happens when you set attributes and characterData to true? Your code is quite similar to the moz example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example_usage

Comment: No change in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put

```
subtree: true
```

It should be

```
document.getElementById('contentEditableElement'), 
    {
        attributes: false, 
        childList: true, 
        characterData: false,
        subtree: true
    }
```